# Tailwind CSS not loading custom classes on React app

Tags: css, reactjs, tailwind-css

I have a React app that uses Tailwind CSS and multiple themes.

index.css:

```
@tailwind base;
@tailwind components;
@tailwind utilities;

@layer base {
  [data-theme='default'] {
    --color-primary: #008cba;
    --color-secondary: #e7e7e7;
    --color-success: #4caf50;
    --color-danger: #f44336;
  }

  [data-theme='secondary'] {
    --color-primary: #af8ffa;
    --color-secondary: #e7e7e7;
    --color-success: #4caf50;
    --color-danger: #f44336;
  }
}

@layer components {
  .btn-primary {
    background-color: theme(colors.primary);
    color: theme(colors.danger);
  }
  .btn-secondary {
    background-color: theme(colors.secondary);
    color: black;
  }
  .btn-success {
    background-color: theme(colors.success);
  }
  .btn-danger {
    background-color: theme(colors.danger);
  }
}
```

tailwind.config.js:

```
/** @type {import('tailwindcss').Config} */
export default {
  content: ['./index.html', './src/**/*.{js,ts,jsx,tsx}'],
  theme: {
    extend: {
      colors: {
        primary: 'var(--color-primary)',
        secondary: 'var(--color-secondary)',
        success: 'var(--color-success)',
        danger: 'var(--color-danger)',
      },
    },
  },
  plugins: [],
};
```

I defined a simple button component that takes a variant ('primary' | 'secondary' | 'success' | 'danger') as a prop:

```
import { ButtonProps } from './Button.types';

function Button({ variant, children, ...rest }: ButtonProps) {
  return (
    <button
      className={`border-none py-2 px-4 text-center inline-block text-md border-r-4 cursor-pointer btn-${variant}`}
      {...rest}>
      {children}
    </button>
  );
}

export default Button;
```

The problem is that the custom .btn- classes, like .btn-primary, don't get applied consistently. Most of the time they won't render, however if while the app is loaded I change the btn class and I hardcode something btn-primary then the styles load fine. After that I can change it back to btn-${variant} and the styles load fine. At this point I can also change the styles in index.css and the new styles also get applied.

As a side note, when they don't get rendered they won't even show in the styles tab in google developer tools. If I inspect the element the class is there, but the styles don't show in the styles tab.

I don't really know what I'm missing here.

Answer (score 0, accepted):

As per [the documentation](https://tailwindcss.com/docs/content-configuration#dynamic-class-names):

> The most important implication of how Tailwind extracts class names is that it will only find classes that exist as *complete unbroken strings* in your source files.
>
> If you use string interpolation or concatenate partial class names together, Tailwind will not find them and therefore will not generate the corresponding CSS:
>
> Don't construct class names dynamically
>
> ```html
> <div class="text-{{ error ? 'red' : 'green' }}-600"></div>
> ```
>
> In the example above, the strings `text-red-600` and `text-green-600` do not exist, so Tailwind will not generate those classes.
>
> Instead, make sure any class names you’re using exist in full:
>
> Always use complete class names
>
> ```html
> <div class="{{ error ? 'text-red-600' : 'text-green-600' }}"></div>
> ```

Comment: I'm trying to avoid having multiple nested ternary operators in the className prop so I've tried to create a btnVariant variable to hold the value of the class, but that still didn't work. Then is having ternary operators in className the only way?

Comment: As per [the documentation](https://tailwindcss.com/docs/content-configuration#dynamic-class-names), you could have a variant map of class names.